# GitHub Actions how to use stdout from bashfile

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have the following GitHub action yml file that comments on the PR with stdout. However, I have noticed when using a bash script `bash.sh`, the comment is empty. Inside `bash.sh` it runs a series of commands that generates output. Is there any way to get the output from `bash.sh`?

````
- name: "Run bash"
  id: plan
  run: ./bash.sh

- name: "Comment PR"
  uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
  env:
    STDOUT: "```${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}```"
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    script: |
      github.issues.createComment({
        issue_number: context.issue.number,
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        body: process.env.STDOUT
      })
````

Comment: In the github action runner, if you want to save the output from a script into an env variable, the output needs to be printed in the file, then you could get it by doing something like `OUTPUT=./bash.sh` or `OUTPUT=$(./bash.sh)`.